# If is reasonable/how to decrease json OData result size

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI application has OData controller which returns lot of  tablular data in OData v4 format in json to javascript/jquery client in browser:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyODataController : ODataController
{


    [Queryable]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
  ...
```

Returned result is table which have same columns for every row.
It seems that OData requires that every row must have also  property specified.
Is increases data size with redunant values for every row.

How to fix this so that properties can specified at once for all rows ? For example, maybe json array can used for row data?
Or is it OK to return such verbose data? How much it affects to perfomance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case I understand your question:

you can use the `$select` to return the column what you expect.

You can use the `$filter' to return the rows what you expect.

Comment: Lot of columns and rows needs to be returned, this cannot limited. I asked how to remove property name from every row and send column names only once per response since they are same for every row.